# Remove light reflection from eyes

Tags: after-effects, post-production

I have a video with a man speaking (very stable, motion tracking on his eyes works perfectly)

The problem is each eye has reflections of 4 light sources, so each eye looks like it has 4 white pupils inside the iris. The black pupil suffers from these reflections too. <s>I hope you can understand what i mean.</s> See the following photo.

What effect i need to apply to remove these light reflections and make his iris look natural brown (his original color)? Tried lowering brightness, but his eyes became like big black eyes of a shark.

What to do? Do i need some sort of effect and an artificial black pupil on top?

I'm asking this question hoping this is a somewhat common problem so maybe there is a solution already for that.

Here is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if you could add an image to your question...?

Comment: Ditto.  Could you post a pic?  Perhaps you're being too critical.  Usually, these sort of reflections are desirable.  Are you familiar with the expression, "the apple of someone's eye"?

Comment: @poor added photo, will add an answer shortly, since i managed to solve this, of course answers are welcome! :D

Comment: @JasonConrad added photo, yes 1 reflection is desirable, but these are way too much ouch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using 1) motion tracking and 2) a good picture of an eye.

1. With adobe after effects i managed to track the motion of the problematic iris. The result was a very precise motion path of the iris for the whole video. Great.
2. Then i used a good picture of brown eyes (google images) from which i cropped a circular selection which had "some" iris and the pupil. I made that circular selection a little transparent around the edges and finally had this result:

[image]

3. Using that image (2) on the motion path (1), the result was excellent. I had to play a bit with the colors to make the new iris blend with the original iris which "embraced" the new one.

(Fortunately, person wasn't blinking.)

p.s. More answers are welcome!